# Hardware Frequency Steps - Intel P-State vs ACPI CPUFREQ

Tags: linux, intel, acpi, cpu-frequency

I have `Intel Xeon Phi 7210` running `CentOS 7` with kernel `3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64`. I am comparing what frequency steps are available when I boot system into `intel p-state` vs when the system uses `acpi cpufreq`. I run `sudo cpupower frequency-info` to get following two logs.

**Intel P-State**

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 1000 MHz - 1.50 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 1.40 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 1.30 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

**ACPI CPUFREQ**

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us
  hardware limits: 1000 MHz - 1.30 GHz
  available frequency steps:  1.30 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 1000 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative userspace powersave ondemand performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1000 MHz and 1.30 GHz.
                  The governor "conservative" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 1000 MHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

Why does two different scaling drivers show different hardware frequency limits? For `intel p-state`, I see frequency limits from `1GHz` to `1.5GHz` and on other hand `acpi cpufreq` shows `1GHz` to `1.3GHz`.

As per datasheet, the above processor can run at `1.5GHz` with turbo boost, is that the reason why it's not available for `acpi cpufreq`?

Any specific reason why this is the case?

Thanks.